# AJAX requests taking longer than normal requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, iis

Morning all,

We're building an Angular app and we're stumped by a particular problem whilst trying to speed the thing up. I've attached two photos, one is of an AJAX request made from within a larger page.

[image: XHR request as part of larger page]

And this one is of the same request, same parameters, etc, made only a few seconds after (and it's not cache issue).

[image: request on its own]

The environment is:

- IIS
- PHP5.4
- Memcache currently disabled

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? Angular does not make HTTP requests - it just wraps XMLHttpRequest into a convenient form for you. It has no control over how long the request takes to complete once it is started, and factors like IIS and Memcache are irrelevant to it.

You need to discuss what you're doing in your PHP code on the server and re-tag the question with appropriate markers for the communities (like PHP developers) who help out in those areas.